# How to have row deduplication when inserting into BigQuery using the Storage Write API without offsets?

Tags: google-bigquery

Given an application inserting events as rows into a BigQuery table using the Java API, I'd like to avoid accidentally inserting the same event/row multiple times (because of errors, retries, etc.).

Every event, I'm inserting as a row, has a unique UUID, but I don't have a stream offset. (It's not guaranteed the events arrive in a fixed order in my application, because it's consuming from a Kafka topic with multiple partitions parallelly.)

Using the [BigQuery legacy streaming API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery), I was able to rely on [Best effort de-duplication](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency) using the `id` parameter of the following function.

```
com.google.cloud.bigquery.InsertAllRequest.RowToInsert.of(String id, Map<String, ?> content)
```

The new [BigQuery Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api) (in committed mode) does have an exactly-once guarantee, but only if one can provide an offset.

```
com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.JsonStreamWriter.append(JSONArray jsonArr, long offset)
```

If I understand the docs correctly, the offsets need to be strictly ascending, which is something I can't provide in my use case.

Is there some way to solve my problem, i.e., having (best-effort or exact) deduplication using the new Storage Write API?

Comment: Can you please provide more information and clarify on your use case and explain why you can’t provide offset in your use case?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT Thanks for the remark. The reason is, my application is consuming from a Kafka topic with multiple partitions parallelly. I just edited my question accordingly.

Comment: How about adding a global id generator to attached global id to each message after consume message from Kafka topic?

Comment: @zangw If I understand correctly, to have a strictly monotonic increasing ID for each Kafka message, I'd need to funnel them all through one bottleneck (get artificial stream offset and insert), which not only might be bad for performance in this highly-parallel scenario (multiple Kafka-to-BigQuery-worker replicas in K8s) but also still problematic in case something fails.

Comment: @zangw E.g., a worker fetches a batch of messages from one Kafka topic partition, and only part of it can be inserted, I'd need to very carefully manually manage committing consumer offsets back to Kafka. Basically, I'd arrive at a solution, in which I would already guarantee exactly-once semantics in my application alone, thus no longer needing to use the `offset` parameter from `JsonStreamWriter.append` anymore. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems better to guarantee exactly-once semantics in my application alone

Comment: Yes, the strictly monotonic increasing ID could cause complex logic in handling messages between Kafka and Bigquery. I would prefer to insert all data into Bigquery from Kafka without caring exactly-once logic and filter the duplicate messages on Bigquery through SQL. IMO, both Kafka and Bigquery are the message holder, maybe there is no need to filter messages in them.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I also thought about retroactive deduplication in BigQuery using SQL. While it's simple to implement, it creates additional costs when doing it on many TB of data. Maybe I can optimize by just processing the most recent data partitions of the table(s). Still, I think it's sad that it was so easy with the old Streaming API, and it's so hard with the new Storage API. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: might be worthwhile exploring other options using pub/sub and/or dataflow to BQ as well... https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/handling-duplicate-data-in-streaming-pipeline-using-pubsub-dataflow

Answer (score 0):

If setting offset for the write API is not the option for you. There are three other ways which you can consider:

1. Using Dataflow to deduplicate the data: You can try implementing dataflow to window different kafka partitions and deduplicate data within the dataflow window either with bigquery write API or other beam deduplicate method. You can refer to this [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/after-lambda-exactly-once-processing-in-cloud-dataflow-part-3-sources-and-sinks).
2. First write into the staging table and merge into the final table. However, in the comment, you have said that you don’t prefer it, due to the cost issue.
3. Manually (or set scheduler) to delete any of the duplicate values.  Example SQL can be found on the official [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#manually_removing_duplicates).

Out of those options, It’s recommended using Dataflow as a cushion to process the data before writing into the storage, and this shouldn’t become the bottleneck as Dataflow comes with an autoscale feature.

Comment: Thanks! I had not considered Dataflow yet, because my Kafka cluster is not in the cloud, but on-premise. The manual (or scheduled) deduplication using SQL would work nicely but it would also increase the costs.